# Attempting to use gettext to internationalize a php site

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

Okay, I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$locale = "es";
//$locale = $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"];
//if (isSet($_GET["locale"])) $locale = $_GET["locale"];
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", 'UTF-8');
textdomain("messages");

echo(getenv("LC_ALL"));
echo("<br>");
echo gettext("Hello World!");
?>
```

I have created Spanish messages.po and messages.mo files and stored them in a subdirectory in the directory where the above code is. The path to said directory is:

locale/es/LC_MESSAGES

according to phpinfo, gettext is enabled on the web server I am on (hosted by A Small Orange).

Calling the page shows the getenv call returns 'es', but the original English string comes out, not the expected Spanish. I have also tried with _("Hello World!"), also to no avail.

I get no warnings, no errors, no nothing.  So, I am at a complete loss as to how to even troubleshoot where this may be failing.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It may not be the problem, but "./locale" is a relative path; if your script is running anywhere but that one directory, then it will always break.

Comment: While it is possible that this is the issue, I have tried puttin the whole path: /home/marklybr/public_html/   and this has also proven to provide no change.  I really wish I had some warning messages or logging capability so I could see what the system is trying to do and why it is giving up and deciding that English is simply the best opiton....

Comment: have you try restart the apache server? I also have the same problem but when I try restart the apache server, it works

Answer (score -1):

I might be wrong but, try changing...

```
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");
```

to

```
putenv("LC_ALL=".$locale);
putenv("LANGUAGE=".$locale);
```

Comment: You are wrong :)  Double quotes does perform variable interpolation.

Comment: Stack is not completely wrong @ElYobo. While this will NOT solve the problem, both will work correctly. ;)

Comment: Stack's suggestion didn't change the behaviour at all, so the answer is wrong.